# Add additional data to block (magento 2)

Tags: magento2

I am trying to override magento 2 core block in path:

```
module_sales/block/adminhtml/totals.php
```

But I was not able to do that through preferences since everytime core block is called and not my custom defined in preference. So my thoughts are to try with observer.

Is it possible to load observer after block method is being executed and then to add some additional data to result of that block method.

For example.

In specified block (mentioned above) I would like to add some data to result of function _initTotals inside that block. Result is array so I would like to add some additional data to that array.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my question:

The block:

```
module_sales/block/adminhtml/order/totals.php
```

has been extending the block that I was trying to extend so basically the answer is to extend that block above.